# Use lookup value within concat function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup

I am having some difficulty producing a string where I am attempting to use a lookup value within a concat function.

Below is the code I am trying to execute. - Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

```
%%[
SET @height = Lookup("PKGlookup1", "HEIGHT", "PRODUCT_KEY_GROUP", @product_key_group)
SET @weight = Lookup("PKGlookup1", "WEIGHT", "PRODUCT_KEY_GROUP", @product_key_group)

IF @height == "0" 
THEN SET @weightheight = Concat(Weight:, " ", @weight)
ELSE SET @weightheight = Concat(Height:, " ", @height)
ENDIF     
]%%
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're missing quotes around the string literals being passed to the Concat functions. Try...

```
Concat("Weight: ", @weight)
Concat("Height: ", @height)
```

Comment: Thank you sir. - Feel silly for this one since my lookup function has similar syntax, but nonetheless I really appreciate you providing the correct answer.

Cheers!